# Google Shopping module that use Shopping Content API v2?

Tags: google-api, mage-googleshopping

As i believe you already know Google is retiring the Shopping Content API v1 at the end of February 2015. After this date  all API requests to the Content API v1 will no longer work and our products will no longer be visible in Product Listing Ads.

Do you know any good Google Shopping module that use Shopping Content API v2?

Answer (score 3):

I have developed an Google Shopping API v2 version based on the original Magento GoogleShopping module with some further improvements.

You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/bluevisiontec/GoogleShoppingApi

It migrates the data from the original Magento GoogleShopping module. The only thing which is a bit more complicated is, that for OAuth2 a Google Developer Project hast to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can also check these extension that extension is working fine
if you don't mind then you can use that.

https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions